# How to set hibernate cache properties?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, redis

I'm using Hibernate second level cache in a Java spring project and RedissonRegionFactory as a cache provider, in order to set cache properties
like ttl I added this line to `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.redisson.entity.expiration.time_to_live=10000
```

However I have different cache regions and I want to set for each one a special ttl, instead of setting a general one for all caches.
How can I customize cache properties individually, and is it possible to do this in java class instead of the `application.properties` file?
Any help is appreciated!